# undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

This code throws an error:

```rb
Employee.first.company.employees
```

Error text:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Company::Employee:Module)

In parallel, there are links for this code:

```rb
Employee.first.country.employees
```

And it works fine.

I can't understand why the error occurs for Company. The models are close by. In them, the code for company and country is almost identical. Links are direct, indexes too, without class_name and the like.

```rb
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  belongs_to :company

  belongs_to :country, optional: true

  validates :company, presence: true

  # ...
```

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy

  # ...
```

```rb
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees, dependent: :nullify

  # ...
```

For what reasons might this not work?

Comment: please show your db structure/data

Comment: @Thanh Please clarify your question. I cannot show the whole structure.

Comment: Do you have any other class/module named Company, even a nested one?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean There is only "Companies" used in templates (from ViewComponent; for example: `Companies::ListComponent.new`). Otherwise I use something like "CompanySomeWord".

Comment: @Colibri Just Employee, Company, Country tables are enough. I just want to know how you set up relationships of them

Comment: @DanielSindrestean You were right. I found the mention of "Company" that was hidden from me. Thank you. Oh, this autoload from Rails))

Comment: you're welcome, do you mind if I turn that into an answer?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean Yes of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NoMethodError (undefined method relation_delegate_class..)` can be caused by having multiple classes/modules with the same name even though in different folders (because of the way [autoload](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) works)